# RDF based property file

Tags: rdf, turtle-rdf

i want to create an RDF turtle format file which has configuration for my input and output. Following is the code i have came up with :

```
@prefix ex:  <http://www.example.com/ex#> .
@prefix rdf:  <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> .
@prefix rdfs:  <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> .
@prefix ebucore:  <http://www.ebu.ch/metadata/ontologies/ebucore/ebucore#>.

#ex:hasHeterogeneity can have multiple heterogeneites seperate by ","#

#generateFiles  enables or disables generation of files.#

ex:seed-1
     ex:hasHeterogeneity   "M1,M2";
     ex:hasInputPath       "C:\\seed-1.txt"
     ex:hasOutputPath      "C:\\output"
     ebucore:filename       "seed-1.txt";
     rdf:type               ex:Heterogeneity .

ex:seed-2
         ex:hasHeterogeneity   "M2,M3";
         ex:hasInputPath       "C:\\seed2.aml"
         ex:hasOutputPath      "C:\\output"
         ebucore:filename       "seed-2.aml";
         ex:generateFiles      "true";
         rdf:type               ex:Heterogeneity .
```

My goal is to have input file seed1.aml and have its input and output path and type of heterogeneity it contains. However M2,M3 are codes of these heterogeneities but im not sure if i can put it like literals this in the rdf. i need do define what they are first and then connect it to my rdf.

```
m1 a ex:Heterogeneity ;
m1 schema:name "Data types"@en;
m2........
```

Then, someway to connect in this way:

```
 ex:seed-1
 ex:hasHeterogeneity m1 , m2
```

Any help would be appreciated for a final output.

Comment: Your file isn't well formed.  Some of the lines are missing semicolons, e.g., `ex:hasOutputPath      "C:\\output"` has no semicolon at the end. The file shouldn't parse like this.

Comment: thanks for pointing out, it was a typo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> However M2,M3 are codes of these heterogeneities but im not sure if i
>   can put it like literals this in the rdf.
>
> ```
> ex:seed-2
>          ex:hasHeterogeneity   "M2,M3";
> ```

If you need multiple literal values, why not actually use multiple values.  E.g.,

```
ex:seed-2
   ex:hasHeterogeneity "M2", "M3" ;
   ex:hasInputPath       "C:\\seed2.aml" ;
   # ...
```

Then you can actually query for the values individually.   E.g., if you've defined the values in another place, e.g.:

```
ex:M2 rdfs:label "M2" ;
    # ...
```

Then you could write a SPARQL query like

```
?seed ex:hasHeterogeneity ?hLabel .
?heterogeneity rdfs:label ?hLabel .
```

That said, rather than using string values, why not just use the heterogeneity values directly, as in:

```
ex:seed-2
   ex:hasHeterogeneity ex:M2, ex:M3 ;
   ex:hasInputPath       "C:\\seed2.aml" ;
   # ...
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked great. However, I don't want my subject to be the file name. Any other alternative I can think of? since it's my input file doesn't make sense to put it there. something like heterogeneity-1?                           
     ex:hasID               "Heterogeneity-1";

Comment: @omar I don't know what you mean by "don't want the subject to be the filename". I didn't mention any filenames here.